Target page, context or browser has been closed' with multiprocessing and sync_playwright in python
I have a problem that I have not been able to solve. The DispatcherServiceclass is the class that controls the other two, theoretically it should query an instance of a mongo base, retrieves a cookie from that instance and starts a playwright with chromium loading that cookie in its context. First, the build_worker_process method is called which in turn calls the run method of the FacebookProcess class, which in turn calls two methods of the FacebookService class: first the verify_status method is called and works correctly. However, calling the init_scraper method throws the exception Target page, context or browser has been closed even though I never closed the browser or the playwright. I have already tried loading the prepare_browser method inside the __init__ of the same class but I still get the error; but if I reuse the page I used with verify_status in init_scraper everything works fine; however, I can't reuse the same page because I need to open different pages for different purposes.  The main  method starts two processes and from it, they start the others. I hope you can help me to check why the error is occurring.
The main.py:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    node = WorkerNodeService()
    node.init() # Works fine. Just random class
    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=execute_all_redis, args=(q1, q2,)) # Works fine. A redis consumer class
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=execute_all_dispatcher, args=(q1, q2,)) # Browser context dies
    p2.start()

The DispacherService.py file:
from Playwright.packages.utils.Logger import Logger
from Playwright.packages.multiprocess.FacebookProcess import FacebookProcess
from Playwright.packages.service.CookiesFacebookService import CookiesFacebookService


class DispatcherService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.log = self.logger.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.instances_service = CookiesFacebookService()
        self.list_of_processes = []

    def init(self):
        node = os.environ.get("NODE", "node")
        for i in self.instances_service.find_by_node(node):
            self.build_worker_process(i)

    def build_worker_process(self, instance):
        fb_process_object = FacebookProcess(instance)
        self.list_of_processes.append(fb_process_object)
        fb_process_object.run()


def execute_all_dispatcher(q1, q2):
    ds = DispatcherService()
    ds.init()

The FacebookProcess.py file:
from Playwright.packages.utils.Logger import Logger
from Playwright.packages.service.FacebookService import FacebookService


class FacebookProcess:
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.facebook_service = FacebookService(instance)
        self.instance = instance # Dict
        self.to_run = False
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.log = self.logger.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    def run(self):
        if not self.to_run:
            self.to_run = True
            self.facebook_service.prepare_browser()
        while self.to_run:
            if not self.facebook_service.verify_status():
                self.log.error("Error.")
            time.sleep(3)
            self.facebook_service.init_scraper()
            time.sleep(3600)

The FacebookService.py file:
import os
import sys
import time
import base64
import traceback
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from Playwright.packages.utils.Logger import Logger
from Playwright.packages.utils.BrowserParams import options
from Playwright.playwrightbrowser.PlaywrightScraper import PlaywrightScraper


class FacebookService:
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.playwright = None
        self.browser = None
        self.instance = instance # Dict
        self.cookie = instance["reqCookies"]
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.options = options
        self.log = self.logger.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    def prepare_browser(self):
        try:
            self.playwright = sync_playwright().start()
            self.browser = self.playwright.chromium.launch(**self.options)
        except Exception as ex0:
            try:
                self.log.error(f"Error launching Playwright: {repr(ex0)}. Retrying...", traceback.format_exc())
                time.sleep(8)
                self.playwright = sync_playwright().start()
                self.browser = self.playwright.chromium.launch(**self.options)
            except Exception as ex1:
                self.log.error(f"Error launching Playwright: {repr(ex1)}. Finishing execution.", traceback.format_exc())
                sys.exit()

    def init_scraper(self):
        # page = self.browser.contexts[0].pages[0]  # Works fine, but need new page, not the same
        page = self.browser.new_page() # CONTEXT OR BROWSER DESTROYED BY SOME REASON
        page.context.add_cookies(self.cookie)
        PlaywrightScraper(page).launch_playwright()
        self.stop_browser()

    def verify_status(self):
        page = self.browser.new_page() # Works fine
        page.context.add_cookies(self.cookie)
        page.goto("https://www.facebook.com")
        if ("checkpoint" not in page.url) and not (
                page.is_visible("//div/h1[contains(text(), \"Connect with people who share your interests.\")]")):
            self.log.info(f"Instance: OK")
            page.close()
            return True
        else:
            self.log.info(f"Instance: FAIL. Check instance.")
            page.close()
            return False

    def make_screenshots(self):
        page = self.browser.new_page()
        page.context.add_cookies(self.cookie)
        page.screenshot(path="ss.jpg")
        with open("ss.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
            converted = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
        page.close()

    def stop_browser(self):
        self.log.info(f"Shutting down instance: {node}")
        try:
            self.browser.close()
            self.playwright.stop()
        except Exception:
            self.log.error("Error trying to close and quit Playwright. Retrying")
            self.browser.close()
            self.playwright.stop()

Finally, the PlaywrightScraper.py file:
class PlaywrightScraper:
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.log = self.logger.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    def launch_playwright(self):
        page = self.page
        page.goto("https://www.facebook.com", wait_until='load')
        ...

I know that those are kinda many classes but I need to create a new FacebookProcess for each instance found in database, also, it's how I was asked to do it. Hope you can help me.
Error logs:
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Personal/PycharmProjects/playwright/Playwright/packages/service/FacebookService.py", line 46, in init_scraper
    page = self.browser.new_page()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_generated.py", line 14584, in new_page
    self._sync(
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py", line 115, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser.py", line 178, in new_page
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(inner)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 495, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser.py", line 172, in inner
    context = await self.new_context(**params)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser.py", line 127, in new_context
    channel = await self._channel.send("newContext", params)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 63, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 490, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/playwright/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 101, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._errors.TargetClosedError: Target page, context or browser has been closed

Versions that I use:
Python 3.10.12 
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on WSL2
playwright 1.41.1
chromium latest version


This looks really overengineered. Can you minimize the failing example? Remove any code not necessary to repro the problem and make it simple and runnable, preferably one file. I haven't bothered trying to run this, but init_scraper stops the browser immediately after launching it--why? On the second loop of while self.to_run:, init_scraper can't be called again because the previous call closed out the browser. The classes here don't make much sense and the cut points are unclear and confusing. I'd just write simpler, less fussy, more imperative code until you really need to engineer.

Saldy, I just follow the guidelines, also think that's unnecessesarily confusing. I try this: calling the stop_browser and prepare_browser just before each new creation page and it works, but I don't think it's the right approach, the context should keeps alive but just dies for no reason. I added a self.to_run = False in the while loop you mentioned.
